# How to combine reducers to get a nested tree state in react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have some reducers that were combined using combineReducer:

```
 import reducer1 from './tree1/reducer1/reducer';
 import reducer2 from './tree1/reducer2/reducer';
 import reducer2 from './reducer3/reducer';

 combineReducers({
  reducer1,
  reducer2,
  reducer3,
})
```

I tried to change the state structure to a tree-like structure, by using multiple or nested combineReducers, like:

```
 import reducer1 from './tree1/reducer1/reducer';
 import reducer2 from './tree1/reducer2/reducer';
 import reducer2 from './reducer3/reducer';
 import treeReducer from './tree1'

combineReducers({
  tree1: combineReducers({
       reducer1,
       reducer2
     }),
  reducer3,
  reducer4,
})
```

until now everything is good
but the problem is that I want to add a tree1 reducer to the structure. (actually, tree1 is a reducer itself, which other reducers (states) are its children.)
but I can either inject tree1 reducer or combineReducers function to the tree1 key!

Comment: what is the motiviation behind this?

Comment: I want to have full control over tree1's children, for example deleting them (deleting the cache). of course, I can add an action inside each child to clean their state, but it's a lot of work. there are so many children.

Comment: Syntax is correct. What's the problem?

Comment: I edited the post and clarified the problem